# How to send values from LocalStorage to Flask @app.route()?

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, flask

Recently, i've been using Flask, but i just wanna ask how to `POST` data from `LocalStorage` of the web browser to `@app.route`

part of main.py

```py
@app.route("/authenticate/post", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def posting():
  posts = request.form['post']
  return render_template("testing.html", post=posts)
```

Here i'm making a small web-based "posting and sharing app" just like Instagram, the var `posts` is the Post Content submitted via `textarea` of html, and is working perfectly fine. All i need now is how to get the data stored on `LocalStorage` of a user's browser. Which is the Username of the user. How can i retrieve the **Username** of the user that is stored on the `LocalStorage` and do POST request to my `@app.route()`

Index.html

```html
  <div class="posting">
  <h5>Write Something &amp; Post!</h5>
    <form method="POST" action = "/authenticate/post" autocomplete="off">

<textarea class="books" placeholder="Say something!" id="post" name="post" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="200"></textarea>
      <br><br>
<input id="enter" type="submit" class="books" value="Post!" onclick="getname()">
    </form>
</div>
```

The `getname()` function of my main.js

```js
function getname() {
    let name = localStorage.getItem('username');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change the submit input to a simple button:

```
<div class="posting">
  <h5>Write Something &amp; Post!</h5>
    <form id="post-form" method="POST" action = "/authenticate/post" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username">

        <textarea class="books" placeholder="Say something!" id="post" name="post" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="200"></textarea>
        <br><br>
        
        <button type="button" class="books" id="enter" onclick="submitForm()">Post!</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then handle the form submit in JS, while setting a hidden input in the form:

```
function submitForm()
{
    let name = localStorage.getItem('username');

    // set the value of the hidden input
    document.getElementById("username").value = name;

    // submit the form
    document.getElementById("post-form").submit();
}
```

OR

You still need the hidden input, but on DOM ready event, you could set the input value:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let name = localStorage.getItem('username');

    // set the value of the hidden input
    document.getElementById("username").value = name;
})
```

This way you can ensure that your "username" will be posted.